# Make instances rotate outwards according to proximity using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry, geometry-nodes, empty

I have instanced some grass on a plane, and i want an empty (or mesh, or whatever works) to go trough it, while folding, or rotating grass away so it makes a path. Ive been trying to do this with geometry nodes and geometry proximity but no luck, any help?

Answer (score 6):

We can align their rotation to the vector from the empty controller to their position, and modulate this alignment by the distance from the empty controller:

[image]

Notice the instancing Suzanne in the background; her origin is located at her bottom.  This is important because the rotation will be about that origin.  (I also edited her a bit to stretch her out, so I could make sure I could see what I was doing.)

The map range is simply to tune the fall-off, and this should be done to eye.  Here, anything more than 1.2 units from the empty will be unaffected.

[image]

Comment: i tried your setup with 3.0 and i got: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqAFN.gif but i don't think it is your fault, it think it is the Blender version - although it seems to be the same - might be different ones. On 3.1 it is weird too. Or i made a dumb mistake  - but i double checked.